# ¿Como ejecutar script de php y actualizar vista?

Tags: php, html, sql-server

Necesito que me den una idea de como resolver el siguiente problema...
Se requiere que cuando se haga una busqueda, se registre en una base de datos el producto buscado y la hora, y hay que mostrar los datos de la busqueda en un nuevo formulario, escribir en la base ya está el problema es que meto mi script al inicio del formulario donde se muestran los datos, entonces al recargar la pagina otra vez se vuelve a insertar en la base de datos.

```
                   <form class="" action="detalleProducto.php" method="POST">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre del Producto" pattern="\w{5,12}" name="producto" class="form-control" required>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                        </span>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" >
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                          </button>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                  </form>
```

es la parte donde pido el nombre del producto y al inicio de  detalleProducto.php tengo esto....

```
          $user = $_SESSION['usuario'];
          $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
          $h = new Historial();
          $consulta = $h->registrarConsultas(strtoupper($productoBuscado),$date, $user);
```

y a continuacion se tiene el formulario donde se muestran los datos, y por eso al recargar, se vuelve a ejecutar el registro, no se como separarlo y asociarlo al boton del primer formulario.

Comment: puedes usar ajax. saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mas sencillo que se me ocurre es que lo hagas con AJAX

```
 <form class="" action="detalleProducto.php" id="busqueda" method="POST">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre del Producto" pattern="\w{5,12}" name="producto" id=""producto class="form-control" required>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                    </span>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" >
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                      </button>
                    </span>
                  </div>
              </form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#busqueda").submit(function(){
var data = $("#producto").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "tu_php",
    type: POST,
    data: data,
});
```

});

Comment: No he utilizado JQuery, pero con eso se ejecuta el ajax o hay que meterlo en una funcion javascript y llamarlo por ejemplo en un "onClick" o algo asi?

Answer (score 0):

usando jquery puedes enviar los datos para el script php, capturarlos y guárdalos. Después imprime el resultado de la consulta de la búsqueda con *echo* y colocas los datos en el nuevo formulario (Todo el proceso se realiza en el mismo script). 
Ej:

```
$("#busqueda").submit(function(){
   var valor = $("#producto").val();
   $.post('script.php',{valor:valor}function(data){
       //Pasamos los datos para el nuevo formulario de acuerdo al selector
       //$(selector).html(data.nombre)
   },'json');
   //Ejecutamos return false para evitar que la página se recargue por el submit del formulario.
  return false;
});
```

Nota: la impresión del lado del script php lo que tiene que realizar con *json_encode* en caso que no quiera usar solo tiene que quitar '*json'* del *$.post()*

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que haces la búsqueda con el método POST. Al recargar la página se reenvían las cabeceras, incluyendo lo del formulario, y como en tu script imagino que validas que si existe POST haga algo, pues la condición se vuelve a cumplir y ejecuta el código cada vez que recargas la página.

Yo lo que haría según tu código, es registrar el producto buscado y su hora en un archivo diferente al formulario. Al guardarse la información, redirigir al formulario con los datos del producto.

Esto te sirve para tener más estructurado (y separado) tu código.

Sería algo como lo siguiente:

**formulario.php** tal como lo tienes, pero en el action:

```
action="guardar_detalle.php"
```

O el nombre que quieras colocar. Este archivo guardará la consulta.

**guardar_detalle.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['producto']))
{
  // saneo xss parte 1
  $producto = strip_tags($_POST['producto']);

  // Incluyo mi conexión con DB, saneo antes de insertar en DB con real_escape_string

 // Preparo mi sql e inserto

// Si hubo error al insertar, guardo la query en una archivo log

// Redirijo a detalleProducto.php con header('location: detalleProducto.php?producto=$producto')
}

// Si no entra al if, entonces redirigir a donde quieras
header('location: index.php');
```

Y ahora en **detalleProducto.php** verifico que exista mi variable GET, la cual voy a capturar y volver a aplicar filtros.

```
if(isset($_GET('producto')))
{
  $producto = strip_tags($_GET['producto']);

  // Incluyo mi conexión

  // Hago mi consulta para mostrar los detalles con sus filtros para evitar inyeccción sql

 // Muestro los detalles
}
```

Y listo, aunque recargues la página lo único que hará es volver a consultar la DB de acuerdo a la variable GET y mostrar los detalles.

Debes tomar en cuenta que tal como lo tienes no es la mejor opción debido a las constantes consultas a la DB.

Otra opción es como dicen los otros colegas, cambiar tu lógica usando ajax y hasta es mejor para la experiencia del ususario pues si busca un producto inexistente tendrá que regresar al formulario, o de menos es la impresión que da con la información que colocaste.

Igual mi respuesta no es tan súper detallada por lo mismo, y creo que es innecesario colocar las consultas y todo lo que ya sabes hacer.